# Factory boy with async calls

Tags: python, asynchronous, sqlalchemy, fastapi, factory-boy

I'm trying to use factory boy with async SQLAlchemy, concrete SQLModel ORM and having issue while calling factory boy create method it creates only instance od object but never stored in DB. My factory boy is looking like this

```
session = scoped_session(
    sessionmaker(class_=AsyncSession, bind=engine, autoflush=False)
)


class BaseFactory(SQLAlchemyModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = InitialModel
        abstract = True
        sqlalchemy_session = session
```

and inside coftest I have session that is needed for FastAPI

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="function")
async def session_fixture() -> AsyncSession:
    """Create a new session for a test and rollback changes after test"""
    async_session = sessionmaker(engine, class_=AsyncSession, autoflush=False)
    async with async_session() as session:
        yield session
        for table in reversed(SQLModel.metadata.sorted_tables):
            await session.execute(table.delete())
```

I'm not sure if there is problem with sessions or because of asynchronous calls. When I was working with synchronous calls on same type everything was stored propertly

Comment: Are you using pytest-asyncio and marking your test functions with `@pytest.mark.asyncio`?

Comment: tried with that but without success. it is running async as test but I think that problem is that factory create doesn't await on session.commit (if it provides it) and because od that it never store it in db

Answer (score 6):

Just override `_create` method in your factory:

```
class YourFactory(SQLAlchemyModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = InitialModel
        abstract = True
        sqlalchemy_session = session

    @classmethod
    async def _create(cls, model_class, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = super()._create(model_class, *args, **kwargs)
        async with cls._meta.sqlalchemy_session as session:
            await session.commit()
        return instance
```

Than create instance with `await` inside your async tests or fixtures:

```
instance = await YourFactory()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [async-factory-boy](https://pypi.org/project/async-factory-boy/), which is a factory_boy extension with asynchronous ORM support. Your factories can then use `AsyncSQLAlchemyFactory` (imported from `async_factory_boy.factory.sqlalchemy`) instead of `SQLAlchemyModelFactory`.

```python
from async_factory_boy.factory.sqlalchemy import AsyncSQLAlchemyFactory

class TestModelFactory(AsyncSQLAlchemyFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = TestModel
        session = session

    name = Faker("name")
    created_at = Faker("date_time")

test_model = await TestModelFactory.create()
```